# How to find last message in chat conversation between users in mongo db

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am building a chat system.Here is the chat_history document.

```
{

toUser:123 <Int32>
fromUser:456 <Int32>
message:"message 1" <String>
timeStamp:"2019-10-09 16:39:14:1414",

toUser:456,
fromUser:123, 
message:"Man super man ",
timeStamp:"2019-10-09 16:43:09:0909 PM +05:30",

toUser:101,
fromUser:123, 
message:"last",
timeStamp:"2019-10-09 16:43:09:0909 PM +05:30",


toUser:123 <Int32>
fromUser:456 <Int32>
message:"message 2"
timeStamp:"2019-10-11 16:39:14:1414",

}
```

Above are the sample collections in the document of all chat messages between all the users. Now I need to find the rows of **last message** based on **timestamp** between particular user **for example:123** and other users with 123 has done chatting.

I am new to mongo i need a query in mongo.

Can anybody please help me with query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `const latestChat = await chat_history.findOne({ toUser: 123 }).sort({ timeStamp: -1 }).limit(1) });`

Comment: This will not work I need whether user 123 might have received last msg or he may send the last msg.But thanks.

Comment: Try `const latestChat = await chat_history.findOne({$or: [{ toUser: 123 }, {fromUser: 123}]}).sort({ timeStamp: -1 }).limit(1) });`

Comment: on find one we cannot sort right? and it if we use find also it will give me the last chat with only one user I need with all different users.

Comment: @Akhilkumar check the answer and please accept it as answer(tick mark on left to the answer) if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer with aggregation for this document model but for high performance, I suggest this

**Save timestamp as a `date` object and query as following**

```
db.chat_history.find({$or: [{fromUser: 123}, {toUser: 123}]}).sort({timestamp: -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: @akhil-kumar Hope this answer helps you solve the problem. Please upvote the answer and accept as correct answer if it does. This will help other SO readers.

Comment: no this query is not correct.this gives me only user 123 who sent only but also need fromUser.

Comment: Edited the query to include documents where `fromUser` is 123. This should work for both cases now.